# In Kubernetes, do we still need multiprocess/gunicorn?

Tags: kubernetes, multiprocessing, gunicorn, python-multiprocessing

In a machine-oriented deployment, usually, people would use `gunicorn` to spin up a number of workers to serve incoming requests. (yes, the `worker_class` would further define the behavior within the worker process)

When deploying in a Kubernetes cluster, do we still `gunicorn` (or to be exact, do we still need multiprocess deployment)?

Basically, each running container is a process (in the one-container-per-pod config). Multiple pods running behind a service is already equivalent to what `gunicorn` has to offer. In other words, rely on Kubernetes service instead of `gunicorn`

Is `gunicorn` still needed?

Yes, a pod is not exactly the same as a process (some overhead in each pod for the companion container), but other than that, anything else we may miss from not having `gunicorn`?

## Edited

Clarification: yes, still need `gunicorn` or other `wsgi` `http` server to run the python app. My question is really about the `multiprocess` aspect (as the *multiprocess/gunicor* in the title).

Comment: I don't think there's a best practice yet (and a lot of what people say is motivated by old habits). 

Anecdotally deploying gunicorn to Kubernetes has made it hard to catch memory issues. The OOM killer, kills the gunicorn child processes in the pod, meaning that the pod never actually dies if it runs out of memory. The master process just restarts the child.

This is a problem because nothing gets logged. Furthermore gunicorn's process management is at odds with Kubernetes which has it's own health checks.

Comment: I came here wondering whether uvicorn is sufficient in a kubernetes setup without the need of a process manager as described on https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#using-a-process-manager.

Comment: @Risadinha This is exactly what my OP for. So all the scaling up/down, restarts, readienss/liveness probes, ssl are already being taken care by k8s. currently we are running gunicorn with 1 uvicorn worker.  May drop gunicorn completely later

Answer (score 7):

Gunicorn is used to serve WSGI(Web Server Gateway Interface) applications so it is a server and not just multiprocess orchestration tool. Kubernetes on the hand is an orchestration tool that helps manage the infrastucture. It does not speak HTTP nor does it know anything about WSGI specs. 
In other words, you can't run WSGI applications on bare kubernetes pods, you will still need a WSGI server liike Gunicorn, uWSGI, etc to serve the application.

Comment: hey @Ken4scholars, thanks for the comment. I edited my question to clarify the question.

Comment: @MartinNowosad `python manage.py runserver` lunches the Django development server which has a WSGI server embedded. So you still have a WSGI server. In production, this server is not used as it is not production ready and lacking many features needed in a production environment. That is why in production, you use Gunicorn/uWSGI or other production-ready WSGI servers. You cannot just spin up a k8s pod as it would not be able to talk to your Django app or speak HTTP. Sure, you can run k8s ontop the development server but that is strickly not recommended for the reasons above.

Comment: @MartinNowosad read my post again and my comments - you cannot replace gunicorn with k8s without a WSGI server. The development server you're constantly referring to is also a WSGI server. I specifically mentioned Gunicorn because it was in the post, but I also said without a WSGI server. Maybe try reading the post again. I don't see any point in furthering this conversation so this is my last comment. Have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

> Is gunicorn still needed?

It's not needed really. Kubernetes can handle scaling up and down (pods/containers) the same way that gunicorn does using for example an [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) or a [VPA](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler), combined with other things like the [cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler).

The fact that you don't need it, it doesn't need you can't use gunicorn.  You can perfectly have multiple processes in a pod/container controlled by [resource limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/). Keep in mind that the Kubernetes resource manager will ultimately dictate what the requested and the upper bound for a resource will be for your containers (running in a pod).

Comment: I don't understand, I thought you needed gunicorn to serve the application, without it how does the flask app work?  What does the flask app look like?  Does it look like the basic development apps we see online (hello world)?  Also if we do include gunicorn, do we just set the worker processes to 1?

Comment: You can opt to do the hello world like approach without gunicorn or gunicorn with a 1 process, both work. I just don't see the benefit of gunicorn unless with a single process is faster than the hello world approach

Comment: DO NOT USE RUNSERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.) See: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/which-http-server-for-k8s-gunicorn/7911/2

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use-cases. There is no right on wrong here if one solution suits you better than the other.

We have a similar use-case.
We are running about 30 replica's of the same service. Each pod runs 1 container, which again runs 50 duplicate services.

We could have ended up with 1500 pods running one service, but we've tested that the performance vs. required resources was much better when running only 30 replicas, which runs 50 services per replica.

The only thing we are doing extra is monitoring those 50 services per pod, so if one of them stops, it's being restarted. If all of them have some error, we run a healthcheck on the pod, and the pod is recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the tensorflow model server (see https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple).

In practice, when executing model predictions I've experienced that the performance given the same CPU / GPU resources is worse if attempting to run multiple predictions in parallel (i.e. multiprocess). Matrix computations tend to use low level parallelism via libraries and attempting to use multiple processes does tend to result in slowdowns in my experience. As others have commented, doing your own performance testing for your use case is always the best approach.